# Relatório basico através de SQL

Tags: php, sql

Boa tarde, estou fazendo um sistema de questionários avaliativo, onde possui vários questionários com varias perguntas que fazem referencia a um questionário, que podem ser abertas ou fechadas.

Na tabela de respostas onde irei puxar os relatórios, funciona com os seguintes campos:
**ID / ID_RESPONDENTE / RESPONDENTE / ID_PERGUNTA / PERGUNTA / QUESTIONARIO / TIPO / RESPOSTA**

O que quero é o seguinte, pegar a quantidade de respostas com valor 'Muito bom', 'Bom', 'Ruim, 'Muito Ruim', Exemplo:

**Pergunta / Resposta / Quantidade**

Pergunta 1 - Muito bom - 3

Pergunta 1 - Bom - 4

---

Pergunta 2 -  Muito bom - 5

Pergunta 2 - Bom - 2

Comment: https://www.devmedia.com.br/10-dicas-para-classificar-agrupar-e-sumarizar-dados-em-sql/27555

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagino que cada linha dessa tabela tenha uma resposta a uma pergunta para uma pessoa (tudo 1:1:1), e que esteja desnormalizada para (ID_PERGUNTA, PERGUNTA).

Caso seja este o caso, sua consulta SQL deve ser assim:

```
SELECT Pergunta, Resposta, COUNT(*) AS Quantidade
FROM <tabela>
GROUP BY Pergunta, Resposta
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Comment: obrigado, consegui entender